# How to move sidebar on page up or down pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a blog page like shown below. I want to switch among blog post with page up or page down button. I have created javascript for this purpose but I donot know how to switch sidebar up or down.

Page template

```
|---------------------------------|
|        header                   |
|---------------------------------|

|---------------------|  |--------|
|   blog 1            |  | side   |
|                     |  |    bar |
|---------------------|  |--------|

|---------------------|
|   blog 2            |
|                     |
|---------------------|

|---------------------|
|  blog 3             |
|                     |
|---------------------|
```

Whenever I press *page down*, I should take *header + sidebar* around blog 2; afterwards, if I press again to *page down*, I should take *header + sidebar* around blog 3.

Illustration, on page down

```
|---------------------|
|   blog 1            |
|                     |
|---------------------|

|---------------------------------|
|        header                   |
|                                 |
|---------------------------------|

|---------------------|  |--------|
|   blog 2            |  | side   |
|                     |  |    bar |
|---------------------|  |--------|

|---------------------|
|  blog 3             |
|                     |
|---------------------|
```

My Javascript code;

```
var documentOrder = 0;

function prepareEventHandlers(){
    var blogs = document.getElementsByClassName("blogBox");

    // What should I write to move sidebar and header?

    documentOrder = documentOrder + 1 ;
}

window.onload = function () {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}
```

My webpage body;

```
<body>
    <span id="top"></span>
    <div id="wrapper" class="auto-style2" style="width: 1340px">

        <div class="blankHeader h120 w1180"></div>

        <div id="sidebar"> 
        </div>


        <div id="allBlogPosts">
            <div id="blog1" class="blogBox">
            </div>

            <div id="blog2" class="blogBox">
            </div>

            <div id="blog3" class="blogBox">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: jquery has [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: See this http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/. I think this is what you want. Here is [DEMO](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ScrollingSidebar/)

Comment: Try position:sticky;

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a complete solution, it is just a pointer for you to work on**

Putting it so that you get some direction.

You can either use Jquery plugins to get sticky header and sidebar or you can try to build your own custom functionality as per your requirements.
I used this approach for one of my projects where we needed sticky sidebar and it worked well.

Step 1 : Make header and side bar both position:absolute , you will need a parent wrapper container for all content on your page, this wrapper should be position:relative

```
.wrapperContainer{
position:relative
}

.header{
position:absolute;
top:0; /*Default top can get changed as per your case*/
left:0;
}

.sidebar{
position:absolute;
top:100px;/*Default top can get changed as per your case*/
right:0;
}
```

Step 2 :In your JS add handler to window scroll event and change top position of both header and sidebar as the page scrolls. Use window.pageYOffset property to get how much the window has scrolled vertically, it starts from initial zero value.

```
var windowScrolled = 0, 
    verticalHeaderOffset = 0,
    verticalSidebarOffset = 0,
// These offsets will depend on you requirements, they can be any +ve/-ve number as per your case

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
windowScrolled = window.pageYOffset;
if(windowScrolled > 0){
    $( ".header" ).animate({top: (windowScrolled + verticalHeaderOffset )}, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete, you can remove this whole function handler if not needed
      });
    $( ".sidebar" ).animate({top: (windowScrolled + verticalSidebarOffset )}, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete, you can remove this whole function handler if not needed
      });
}
else{
    $( ".header" ).animate({top: 0}, 1000); // Reset to initial value
    $( ".sidebar" ).animate({top: 100)}, 1000);  // Reset to initial value
}
});
```